# Simple MatLab plot

Tags: matlab

I am a beginner in MatLab and I have to plot (0.5, 0.5), (-0.5, 0.5), (-0.5, -0.5) and (0.5, -0.5) with lines joining the point on the screen. Here is the code I have typed out so far:

---

```
function []=strain_rate_tensor(t)
axis([-1 1 -1 1])
hold on
plot(0.5, -0.5, 'b')
hold on
plot(-0.5, -0.5, 'b')
hold on
plot(0.5, 0.5, 'b')
hold on
plot(-0.5, 0.5, 'b')
hold on
```

---

I get a blank screen when I run this script. What is wrong with my plot? The code is to plot a fluid parcel and then apply some transformations on it.

Comment: That's not a script, it's a function. How are you calling it? Also you haven't joined the lines, but you should still see a single point plotted, not a completely blank screen

Comment: Oh I just run it. And I didn't get any points...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just plotted four dots, you probably either want to plot one or two lines, or four stars or bigger dots.

Make sure to check `doc plot` for examples on how to plot.

I think you want this:

```
plot([0.5 -0.5; -0.5 -0.5; 0.5 0.5; -0.5 0.5]','bo-')
```

---

Sidenote: You only need to use hold on once (before the first or second plot) and you may want to turn it off again after you finish.

Comment: Oh okay...  let me try this. Should I keep the axis the same?

Comment: I do not need the diagonals... do the points join in order of entry?

Comment: @Artemisia I would worry about the axis after the rest of the plot is ok. You indeed need to put the points in in the correct order and may need to input the starting point twice.

Answer (score 4):

```
x1=0.5;
x2=-0.5;
y1=0.5;
y2=-0.5;
x = [x1, x2, x2, x1, x1];
y = [y1, y1, y2, y2, y1];
plot(x, y, 'b-', 'LineWidth', 3);
hold on;
xlim([-1, 1]);
ylim([-1, 1]);
```

You can change the xlim and ylim accordingly.

Comment: Thank you :) let me try this one out.

Comment: @Artemisia If you always want to plot rectangles I would recommend this solution. For the general case you can look at mine.

Answer (score 1):

You have a bit too many hold on there :)

Also you only plot points, here is a simple way to draw connecting lines:

```
clear all
clc

hold all

plot(0.5, -0.5, '*b')

plot(-0.5, -0.5, '*b')

plot(0.5, 0.5, '*b')

plot(-0.5, 0.5, '*b')


line([-0.5 0.5], [-0.5 -0.5],'Color','k','LineWidth',2)
line([0.5 0.5], [-0.5 0.5],'Color','k','LineWidth',2)
line([-0.5 0.5], [0.5 0.5],'Color','k','LineWidth',2)
line([-0.5 -0.5], [-0.5 0.5],'Color','k','LineWidth',2)

hold off

axis([-1 1 -1 1])
```

Giving this:

[image]

Comment: Haha I was under the impression that I need to key in Hold on after every plot :) this is exactly what I wanted :) Thank you so much :)

Comment: Note that from a performance/readability point of view I would actually recommend creating a matrix first, and plotting it in 1 go.

Comment: Totally agree @DennisJaheruddin, actually I wanted to let the OP see how lines were plotted individually. But of course your suggestion and Iakesh's are more efficient.

Comment: So it doesn't really matter which way I do it, but the matrix way is more readable? @Benoit_11

Comment: well the result is ultimately the same, but as your code becomes more complicated you will likely want to simplify it and use the matrix way as proposed. It's up to you really. My answer was the "long way" to do it, but @Iakesh's for example is much more concise.