# Rotating a 2-D plot on MatLab

Tags: matlab

I have a 2-D rectangle that I want to rotate counterclockwise by 45 degrees. I used MatLab help but the functions in there aren't giving me the results I want. I basically have a figure like so:
[Simple MatLab plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25644814/simple-matlab-plot)
and I want to rotate it by 45 degrees. How can I achieve that?

---

Based on the comment, I decided to try and manually calculate all the points just to check if I can do that and turns out that I am not able to get the rotated rectangle. The code is:

```
function []=stress_rate_tensor(t)

clear all 
clc 

plot(0.5, -0.5, 'ob')
plot(-0.5, -0.5, 'ob')
plot(0.5, 0.5, 'ob')
plot(-0.5, 0.5, 'ob')


line([-0.5 0.5], [-0.5 -0.5],'Color','k','LineWidth',1)
line([0.5 0.5], [-0.5 0.5],'Color','k','LineWidth',1)
line([-0.5 0.5], [0.5 0.5],'Color','k','LineWidth',1)
line([-0.5 -0.5], [-0.5 0.5],'Color','k','LineWidth',1)% prints the first rectangle

hold off


axis([-1.5 1 -1 1])
hold on

plot(0.5, 0.5, 'ob')
plot(-0.5, -0.5, 'og')
plot(-1.16, 0.25, 'or')
plot(-0.41, 0.91, 'oy')

line([-1.16 0.25], [-0.5 -0.5],'Color','k','LineWidth',1)
line([-0.41 0.91], [-1.16 0.25],'Color','k','LineWidth',1)
line([-1.16 0.25], [-0.41 0.91],'Color','k','LineWidth',1)
line([-0.5 -0.5], [-1.16 0.25],'Color','k','LineWidth',1) % prints the second rectangle
```

[image]

which is not what I want. Is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: Do you just want to rotate the rectangle or also the axes etc? How about just manually calculating what the new coordinates should be before the plot?

Comment: Just rotate the rectangle. Yes that would work too but isn't there some way I can do it directly?

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin, I have tried your suggestion but I think there is something wrong with my code (which I can't quite point out).

Comment: Actually the two diagonal lines look promising. If you just use the endpoints of those lines to make your plot you should get a rotated rectangle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a piece of code using `hgtransform` (an object that can contain other objects, which lets you treat the hgtransform and its children **as a single entity** with respect to visibility, size, orientation, etc), and `makehgtform` (rotates around the z-axis by `pi/4` radians).

```
% draw square in subplot 1
x1=0.5;
x2=-0.5;
y1=0.3;
y2=-0.3;
x = [x1, x2, x2, x1, x1];
y = [y1, y1, y2, y2, y1];
h = plot(x, y, 'b-', 'LineWidth', 3);  % handle of the plot is h
xlim([-1, 1]);
ylim([-1, 1]);
axis square

pause                                  % press the space bar

%rotate square
t = hgtransform('Parent',gca);
set(h,'Parent',t)
Txy = makehgtform('zrotate',pi/4);     % define a transform matrix
set(t,'Matrix',Txy)
```

[image]

Comment: Ah it was that 'h' that was confusing me. I get it now. Thank you :)